# Operational cost of vector and matrix multiplications

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-optimization

> Find the computational cost of a column vector $x$ multiplied by a row
>   vector $v$

I computed **n** multiplication operations and **n - 1** addition operations,   so would that make for $n(n-1)$ operations overall?

> Find the computational cost of $A*x$ where   A is $n$ by $n$ and $x$
>   is $n$ by $1$

This one i'm struggling with as well I came up with $n^{2}$ multiplications and $n(n-1)$ additions
so would that cout up to $n^{3}(n - 1)$ overall operations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have $n$ and $n-1$ operations, the combined cost is only $2n-1$ (the $n-1$ additions are the total, not per multiplication). For a matrix-vector multiplication you get $n$ times a vector-vector product, so $n(2n-1)$ operations.